# JavaEE - EJB 3.1: Can we force transaction rollback on checked exceptions?

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, jboss, transactions, ejb-3.1

I know that if an EJB method throws a checked exception there is no transaction rollback.

But is there a way to force the rollback when there is a checked exception without having to call `setRollbackOnly()` in each method or create my own Exception class annotated with `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)`?

Currently all our EJB methods are throwing Exception (`mymethod() throws Exception`) and we would like to apply a quick fix to have transaction rollback when this kind of exception is thrown without having to modify each method signature.

Is it possible by modifying a parameter on the application server (currently using Jboss AS 7.1.1), using an annotation on my EJB classes or by defining some kind of interceptor ?

Thanks for any help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to ejb 3.1 specification is also possible to specify the rollback attribute in the deployment descriptor file.

> 14.2.1 Application Exceptions
>
> An application exception does not automatically result in marking the transaction for rollback unless the
> ApplicationException annotation is applied to the exception class and is specified with the
> rollback element value true or the application-exception deployment descriptor element
> for the exception specifies the rollback element as true.

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+AS7.1) you can check how to include the application-exception element in the ejb-jar.xml file.
I think that it could looks like:

```
<assembly-descriptor>
    <application-exception>
        <exception-class>java.lang.Exception</exception-class>
        <rollback>true</rollback>
    </application-exception>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

I never tried this (and I'm not saying that this is good idea) but I think this should works since it is supported by specification.